Calculation of Cramer's V matrix using MathNet.Numerics
How to use MathNet.Numerics to calculate Cramer's V matrix?
Example data and problem:
Finding intercorrelation between each category occurrence.



Time
Categories




14/06 AM
banana, tomatoe


14/06 PM
milk, beans, banana


15/06 AM
apple, meat, tomatoe


15/06 PM
chicken, banana, coffee


16/06 AM
milk, beans, chicken


16/06 PM
tomatoe, orange, coffee



Thanks.

What have you already tried, and what was the struggle. Was it creating the matrix, populating it with associations, or something else?

I'm asking to know where should I begin?

First you want to count all the categories involved, and assign each an index, indicating which row/col in the matrix will relate to that category.
eg
0->banana,
...
N->orange
Next build a matrix of appropriate size (NxN) filled with 0s.
(in MathNet  I think this goes like
Matrix<int> m = Matrix<int>.Build.Dense(N, N);
)
Perform the Cramér's V calculation for each pair of categories and replace the value in the matrix with the calculated value.eg
m(i,j)= cramers_v(categories[i],categories[j])
Very Lastly, after this is working and tested, and if it benchmarks too slow; consider the option to optimise it, maybe by calculating the values before instantiating the matrix, or perform the calculations using matrix/vector operations.

There is no cramers_v implementation which I could use, and I have to implement it myself. Is that correct?

Yes, I think that is correct. At least there isn't one in MathNet.  There may well be an implementation available in another 3rd party library, but your data table will almost certainly need to be restructured into some other format before it can be used.
